"window.matchMedia().matches" incorrect result
I use window, google chrome and checked on FireFox
I set the screen width - 1440px and run function window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1440px)").matches = true, but if I set screen width - 1439px and run function window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1439px)").matches = false.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Why I get different answers?
I found out it when I tried use 2 css @media together and I got some bugs at screen width 1439px and 1440px
@media (max-width: 1439px) {
  @content;
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  @content;
}

All this is repeated every pixel. Not only 1439px and 1440px
I expect a correct work media in js and css

Just a comment, on my Edge/Windows10 when the width is set to 1439 and setting the test width to 1439 or 1439.1 also gives false but gives true when the test width is set to 1439.2 which indicates some sort of rounding problem.
